# In Magento: get static block if product has specific attribute

Tags: magento, attributes, block

I am trying to call the cms block preorder_note IF the product has a value (doesn' matter what value) for the attribute preorder_note. But i cannot get it to work.

This is done on page template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
    <?php if ($_product->getAttribute('preorder_note')): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('preoder_short')->toHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

```
<?php $_howtouse = $this->getProduct()->getPreorder_note(); ?>
<?php if ($_howtouse): ?>
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('preoder_short')->toHtml() ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
```